# Material UI Data Grid onCellEditCommit doesn't work, have some idea why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Trying to get the data after editing with onCellEditCommit but it doesn't work.

Callback fired when the cell changes are committed.

Signature:
function(params: GridCellEditCommitParams, event: MuiEvent, details: GridCallbackDetails) => void
params: With all properties from GridCellEditCommitParams.
event: The event that caused this prop to be called.
details: Additional details for this callback.

Material doc, onCellEditCommit trigger when commit a change.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

onCellEditCommit doesn't work because I had editMode='row' on, in this case, you have to use onRowEditCommit which is the same dependent of editMode.